# Saving and loading TextBox or other control values with a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, file, io, controls

I know that this is possible to be done with application settings, but I want to do it this way:

I have some textboxes and other controls that have `Text` property. I am doing a loop and save the `Name` and `Text` property of them in a text file. The saving statement is like:

```
if (ctrl != null) sb.AppendLine(ctrl.Name.ToString() + ":" + ctrl.Text);
```

When I want to load them back I want to do it this way, but since I can not point to the Name of the controls, I am stuck! (I beleive it was possible in PHP to point to a variable using other variables!)

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ofile.FileName))
{
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("#")) continue; //Line is a commment so skip
            else
            {
                data = line.Split(':');
                //How to set back the text property to the variable?
            }
        }
}
```

What I have in mind now, is to save `Tag` property of controls instead of theire `Name` property. But the problem is my controls are all scaterred in side nested panels and stuff like that so I have to do a lot of LOOPING! to compare theire tags with tags avilable in my saved file (note that I am not going to save all controls in the text file, just some of em!)

What to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find control by it's name if you have access to form's Controls property

```
  var textBox = yourForm.Controls.Find("name", true) as TextBox;
  if(textBox != null)
       textBox.Text = "text";
```

Comment: Does `Form.Controls.Fine()` can find controls which are inside nested panels or layoutpanels?

Comment: Yes,if second parameter is true than it will search in child controls (panels,groupboxes e.t.c)

Answer (score 1):

Store all your controls in a key value pair container where key is the name of the control and value is a reference to the control it self. You can use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to store them. When loading back from the text file, use the key to find the appropriate control and set the text.

Answer (score 1):

your question is unclear .what i understand is you want to write text property to a text file and later restore via txt file if so then its a straighforward solution [in Winform]

to save use the format control-name:text
later on load
use

```
this.Controls[<controlname>].Text=Text
```

i.e. in your context

```
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("#")) continue; //Line is a commment so skip
        else
        {
           string[] data = line.Split(':');
          if(data.Length>0)
          {
            if(this.Controls.ContainsKey(data[0]))
            {
              if(this.Controls[data[0]] is TextBox)
             {
               //generic 
             // this.Controls[data[0]].Text=data[1];
                //or use
                ((TextBox) this.Controls[data[0]]).Text=data[1];
             }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

please note that this.Controls return a Control Object if you want to do any specific operations please Type Cast and then apply.
Also if you try to access

Hope that helps.